# nginx rewrite string and select portions of string

Tags: regex, string, select, nginx, url-rewriting

I currently am trying to figure out if its possible to rewrite

```
http://example.com/sc5147006x0SvS.gif
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/14/06/sc5147006x0SvS/sc5147006x0SvS.gif
```

with the user still using the former url as an address.

the 14 and 06 folders exist in:

sc5 **14** 70 **06** x0SvS

EDIT: The 14 and 06 are always in the same place, they just change value.

is there a way to select those portions from the string after extracting it?

Comment: Are `14` and `06` always on the same place?

Comment: yes they are, which should make this possible (hopefully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite):

```
rewrite ^((/...(..)..(..).+)\.gif)$ /$3/$4$2$1 last;
```

or [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) in location:

```
location ~ ^((/...(..)..(..).+)\.gif)$ {
    alias /path/to/root/$3/$4$2$1;
}
```

Comment: would the location need to change if the /14/06/sc5147006x0SvS/sc5147006x0SvS.gif is in the root?

Answer (score 0):

If you string length is definite as shown in your example. You could use a regex like:

```
(?<=\w\/)((.{3}(.{2}).{2}(.{2}).+)\..+)$
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uL0zQ0)
Here groups are:
1 = `sc5147006x0SvS.gif`
2 = `sc5147006x0SvS`
3 = `14`
4 = `06`
Now use these groups to form the resulting URL.